# Is it possible for the total count in a cluster mode enabled Redis cluster to be fewer than the number of uploaded entries?

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache

I am using a cluster enabled Redis setup with 1 primary node and 1 read replica, and I am attempting to store ~13 million unique entries, but I am noticing that the "count" in each of the 5 primary nodes of my cluster is only ~1.6 million (~8 million total) entries. However, when attempting to hit the cache with each of the 13 million entries, there are definitely not 5 million cache misses. In fact, there are only ~5 cache misses per 3 million entries. There are no TTL issues here as the TTL for all entries is set to months from now.
Is there a good explanation for the seemingly 5 million missing entries?

Comment: Where are you reading the "count" from? `INFO keyspace` command? CloudWatch metric?

Comment: From the Redis UI for each primary node from each shard and adding them all up.